# How to get "name" field out of nix expression?

Tags: nix

Given following `default.nix`,

```
{ stdenv, fetchurl, perl }:

stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "hello-2.1.1";
  builder = ./builder.sh;
  src = fetchurl {
    url = ftp://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/gnu/hello/hello-2.1.1.tar.gz;
    md5 = "70c9ccf9fac07f762c24f2df2290784d";
  };
  inherit perl;
}
```

How can I get the value `hello-2.1.1` from `name` field using `nix-instantiate` ?

```
$ nix-instantiate --eval -E 'name' default.nix 
error: undefined variable ‘name’ at (string):1:1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your `nix-instantiate` invocation is doing, is trying to retrieve `name` from a mostly empty scope. What's missing here is a piece of functionality that is implemented in NixPkgs provides the arguments to your function in `default.nix`.

Let's get the `callPackage` function from your current `<nixpkgs>`:

```
(import <nixpkgs> {}).callPackage
```

`callPackage` requires two arguments, a function that defines the package and an attribute set of overrides. Instead of providing the function directly, you can provide a file reference instead.

```
(import <nixpkgs> {}).callPackage ./. {}
```

Now let's get the name

```
((import <nixpkgs> {}).callPackage ./. {}).name
```

And run it

```
$ nix-instantiate --eval -E '((import <nixpkgs> {}).callPackage ./. {}).name'
"hello-2.1.1"
```

To experiment with Nix, I prefer to use `nix-repl` though. It is easier to use and has tab completion.

```
$ nix-env -iA nixpkgs.nix-repl
$ nix-repl
nix-repl> ((import <nixpkgs> {}).callPackage ./. {}).name
"hello-2.1.1"
```

Comment: Where can I learn more about the nix expression? Is there any good tutorials?  The [manual](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ch-expression-language) doesn't have much example.

Comment: @wizzup Nix itself is quite generic so the manual really explains only the syntax and how derivations work. If you want to understand better existing expressions in nixpkgs, read the nixpkgs manual (https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/), if you wish to understand why things are implemented with some patterns there are the Nix Pills (https://nixos.org/nixos/nix-pills/index.html)